# normalisation function not giving the expected output:

Tags: r

I have some data on prices and I am trying to normalise the data. I start out by trying applying the following function.

```
divs_normalised <- divs %>%
  filter(date >= "1998-09-24") %>%
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  mutate(norm = 1*dividends/first(dividends))


ggplot(divs_normalised, aes(x = date)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = norm, color = symbol, group = symbol), shape = 8)
```

The plot is incorrect. The points should start at 0 but some of them start higher… Where have I gone wrong here? I have tried a few normalisation functions whithout luck.

I can provide the additional normalisation functions if need be. Is my normalisation function correct?

Data:

```
divs <- structure(list(symbol = c("EBAY", "EBAY", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", 
"MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", 
"MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", 
"MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", 
"MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", 
"MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", 
"MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", 
"MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", 
"MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", 
"TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", 
"TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", 
"TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", 
"TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", 
"TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", 
"TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", 
"TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", 
"TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", 
"TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", 
"TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", 
"TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", 
"TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", 
"TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", 
"TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", 
"TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", 
"TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", 
"WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", 
"WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", 
"WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", 
"WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", 
"WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", 
"WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", 
"WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", 
"WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", 
"WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", 
"WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", 
"WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", 
"WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", 
"WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", 
"WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", 
"WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", 
"WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", 
"WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", 
"WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", 
"WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", 
"WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", 
"JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", 
"JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", 
"JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", 
"JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", 
"JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", 
"JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", 
"JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", 
"JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", 
"JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", 
"JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", 
"JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", 
"JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", 
"JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", 
"JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "ORCL", "ORCL", 
"ORCL", "ORCL", "ORCL", "ORCL", "ORCL", "ORCL", "ORCL", "ORCL", 
"ORCL", "ORCL", "ORCL", "ORCL", "ORCL", "ORCL", "ORCL", "ORCL", 
"ORCL", "ORCL", "ORCL", "ORCL", "ORCL", "ORCL", "ORCL", "ORCL", 
"ORCL", "ORCL", "ORCL", "ORCL", "ORCL", "ORCL", "ORCL", "ORCL", 
"ORCL", "ORCL", "ORCL", "ORCL", "ORCL", "ORCL", "IBM", "IBM", 
"IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", 
"IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", 
"IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", 
"IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", 
"IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", 
"IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", 
"IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", 
"IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", 
"IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", 
"IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", 
"IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", 
"IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", 
"IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", 
"IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", 
"IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", 
"IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", 
"IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", 
"IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", 
"IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", 
"IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", 
"IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", 
"IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "ODP", 
"ODP", "ODP", "ODP", "ODP", "ODP", "ODP", "ODP", "ODP", "ODP", 
"ODP", "ODP", "ODP"), date = structure(c(17955, 18046, 12102, 
12340, 12653, 12737, 12829, 12919, 13010, 13102, 13194, 13283, 
13375, 13466, 13557, 13648, 13739, 13830, 13928, 14012, 14110, 
14201, 14292, 14383, 14474, 14565, 14656, 14747, 14838, 14929, 
15020, 15111, 15202, 15293, 15384, 15475, 15566, 15657, 15755, 
15839, 15930, 16028, 16119, 16203, 16301, 16392, 16483, 16574, 
16665, 16756, 16847, 16938, 17029, 17120, 17211, 17302, 17393, 
17485, 17576, 17667, 17758, 17849, 17947, 18031, 4883, 4974, 
5065, 5153, 5247, 5339, 5431, 5522, 5612, 5704, 5796, 5893, 5977, 
6069, 6161, 6252, 6342, 6434, 6528, 6616, 6710, 6801, 6892, 6983, 
7074, 7165, 7257, 7348, 7438, 7530, 7622, 7713, 7803, 7895, 7987, 
8078, 8169, 8261, 8355, 8443, 8534, 8628, 8719, 8810, 8901, 8992, 
9083, 9174, 9265, 9358, 9450, 9541, 9632, 9724, 9818, 9910, 9997, 
10091, 10183, 10275, 10364, 10456, 10548, 10639, 10729, 10821, 
10912, 11003, 11094, 11185, 11277, 11368, 11458, 11550, 11642, 
11733, 11823, 11915, 12009, 12101, 12188, 12282, 12374, 12466, 
12556, 12648, 12739, 12830, 12921, 13012, 13103, 13194, 13285, 
13376, 13468, 13559, 13649, 13741, 13833, 13924, 14015, 14109, 
14201, 14293, 14382, 14474, 14566, 14657, 14747, 14839, 14930, 
15019, 15110, 15202, 15292, 15383, 15474, 15565, 15663, 15751, 
15838, 15936, 16027, 16115, 16209, 16300, 16391, 16479, 16573, 
16664, 16755, 16843, 16937, 17028, 17119, 17210, 17301, 17392, 
17484, 17582, 17666, 17757, 17855, 17946, 18030, 1532, 1713, 
1895, 1999, 2076, 2164, 2266, 2363, 2437, 2533, 2636, 2727, 2801, 
2883, 2997, 3091, 3165, 3263, 3364, 3462, 3529, 3630, 3739, 3819, 
3893, 4009, 4100, 4184, 4260, 4295, 4464, 4548, 4624, 4723, 4824, 
4912, 4988, 5087, 5191, 5279, 5353, 5454, 5555, 5646, 5717, 5818, 
5920, 6010, 6081, 6182, 6284, 6374, 6447, 6549, 6650, 6738, 6815, 
6913, 7015, 7102, 7179, 7278, 7382, 7466, 7543, 7642, 7746, 7831, 
7907, 8008, 8111, 8195, 8279, 8373, 8476, 8559, 8643, 8730, 8839, 
8923, 9007, 9098, 9204, 9289, 9373, 9463, 9570, 9660, 9737, 9841, 
9937, 10030, 10121, 10212, 10303, 10394, 10485, 10569, 10667, 
10758, 10849, 10940, 11031, 11122, 11213, 11311, 11402, 11493, 
11584, 11675, 11766, 11857, 11948, 12039, 12130, 12221, 12327, 
12403, 12494, 12557, 12648, 12767, 12858, 12921, 13012, 13131, 
13222, 13285, 13376, 13495, 13586, 13649, 13740, 13859, 13950, 
14013, 14104, 14224, 14314, 14377, 14468, 14587, 14678, 14741, 
14832, 14951, 15042, 15105, 15196, 15315, 15407, 15469, 15560, 
15679, 15772, 15833, 15924, 16043, 16136, 16197, 16288, 16407, 
16505, 16561, 16652, 16771, 16869, 16932, 17023, 17142, 17233, 
17296, 17387, 17507, 17598, 17661, 17752, 17871, 17969, 18025, 
1189, 4386, 4477, 4565, 4659, 4751, 4842, 4933, 5023, 5116, 5207, 
5297, 5389, 5482, 5571, 5662, 5755, 5849, 5937, 6031, 6122, 6213, 
6304, 6395, 6486, 6578, 6669, 6760, 6850, 6943, 7033, 7123, 7215, 
7308, 7343, 7398, 7488, 7580, 7673, 7763, 7853, 7946, 8040, 8131, 
8222, 8313, 8405, 8495, 8583, 8677, 8769, 8859, 8947, 9041, 9134, 
9224, 9315, 9317, 9408, 9499, 9503, 9594, 9685, 9776, 9777, 9869, 
9959, 10050, 10142, 10233, 10324, 10415, 10506, 10597, 10674, 
10688, 10779, 10870, 10962, 11044, 11053, 11144, 11235, 11330, 
11418, 11509, 11600, 11695, 11785, 11876, 11968, 12060, 12150, 
12241, 12333, 12424, 12514, 12606, 12697, 12789, 12879, 12970, 
13061, 13154, 13244, 13335, 13426, 13521, 13608, 13700, 13791, 
13886, 13977, 14068, 14160, 14251, 14341, 14433, 14524, 14615, 
14706, 14797, 14888, 14980, 15070, 15161, 15252, 15345, 15435, 
12215, 12306, 12397, 12488, 12583, 12674, 12765, 12853, 12947, 
13025, 13130, 13220, 13313, 13404, 13495, 13585, 13677, 13768, 
13859, 13950, 14041, 14133, 14224, 14314, 14406, 14498, 14589, 
14679, 14771, 14865, 14956, 15044, 15138, 15230, 15321, 15412, 
15504, 15595, 15686, 15777, 15868, 15959, 16050, 16141, 16232, 
16324, 16415, 16505, 16597, 16689, 16780, 16871, 16965, 17057, 
17148, 17238, 17330, 17423, 17514, 17604, 17696, 17787, 17878, 
17969, 18060, 14340, 14438, 14526, 14623, 14711, 14802, 14886, 
14988, 15075, 15166, 15254, 15348, 15439, 15532, 15623, 15686, 
15896, 15982, 16073, 16164, 16258, 16349, 16440, 16527, 16622, 
16717, 16804, 16903, 16983, 17081, 17169, 17266, 17364, 17449, 
17540, 17637, 17728, 17819, 17911, 17996, 120, 211, 302, 400, 
491, 582, 673, 763, 854, 945, 1042, 1133, 1219, 1315, 1407, 1497, 
1588, 1680, 1770, 1862, 1953, 2044, 2134, 2226, 2317, 2408, 2499, 
2590, 2681, 2772, 2862, 2955, 3045, 3136, 3226, 3324, 3410, 3506, 
3597, 3688, 3780, 3871, 3961, 4053, 4144, 4235, 4325, 4417, 4508, 
4599, 4690, 4781, 4872, 4963, 5053, 5146, 5237, 5333, 5417, 5515, 
5601, 5698, 5788, 5881, 5971, 6062, 6152, 6244, 6335, 6426, 6517, 
6608, 6699, 6790, 6882, 6972, 7063, 7154, 7245, 7340, 7428, 7522, 
7613, 7704, 7795, 7887, 7977, 8071, 8162, 8253, 8344, 8435, 8526, 
8617, 8708, 8800, 8890, 8981, 9073, 9167, 9254, 9350, 9442, 9533, 
9624, 9715, 9806, 9898, 9988, 10080, 10171, 10263, 10352, 10444, 
10536, 10630, 10717, 10809, 10903, 10995, 11085, 11177, 11269, 
11360, 11450, 11542, 11633, 11724, 11815, 11906, 11997, 12089, 
12179, 12270, 12362, 12454, 12544, 12636, 12730, 12822, 12909, 
13003, 13095, 13187, 13276, 13368, 13460, 13551, 13641, 13733, 
13824, 13915, 14006, 14097, 14189, 14281, 14370, 14462, 14554, 
14648, 14735, 14827, 14921, 15013, 15100, 15194, 15286, 15378, 
15468, 15560, 15651, 15742, 15833, 15924, 16015, 16107, 16197, 
16288, 16380, 16472, 16561, 16562, 16653, 16745, 16839, 16927, 
16930, 17021, 17113, 17205, 17294, 17386, 17479, 17570, 17660, 
17752, 17843, 17934, 18025, 17036, 17127, 17128, 17226, 17309, 
17401, 17492, 17591, 17675, 17766, 17856, 17955, 18039), class = "Date"), 
    dividends = c(0.14, 0.14, 0.08, 0.16, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 
    0.08, 0.08, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.11, 0.11, 
    0.11, 0.11, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 
    0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 
    0.23, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.36, 
    0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.39, 0.39, 0.39, 0.39, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 
    0.42, 0.46, 0.46, 0.46, 0.3, 0.15, 0.162, 0.162, 0.162, 0.16296, 
    0.18504, 0.18504, 0.18504, 0.18504, 0.20496, 0.21, 0.21, 
    0.21, 0.21, 0.23004, 0.23004, 0.23004, 0.23004, 0.255, 0.255, 
    0.255, 0.255, 0.27996, 0.27996, 0.27996, 0.27996, 0.33, 0.33, 
    0.33, 0.33, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.38004, 0.38004, 0.38004, 
    0.38004, 0.39996, 0.39996, 0.39996, 0.39996, 0.42, 0.42, 
    0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.44004, 0.44004, 0.44004, 0.44004, 0.44004, 
    0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.18, 0.18, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 
    0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.055, 0.055, 0.055, 0.055, 
    0.055, 0.055, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.07, 0.07, 
    0.07, 0.07, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.12, 
    0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 
    0.16, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.3, 
    0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.43, 0.43, 0.43, 
    0.43, 0.52, 0.52, 0.52, 0.52, 0.56, 0.56, 0.56, 0.56, 0.6, 
    0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.62, 0.62, 0.62, 0.62, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 
    0.64, 0.0512, 0.0512, 0.03072, 0.03072, 0.01536, 0.02048, 
    0.02048, 0.02048, 0.02048, 0.0256, 0.0256, 0.04608, 0.04608, 
    0.04608, 0.05376, 0.05376, 0.05376, 0.05376, 0.07424, 0.07424, 
    0.07424, 0.07424, 0.09984, 0.09984, 0.09984, 0.09984, 0.06528, 
    0.06528, 0.06528, 0.44032, 0.0896, 0.0896, 0.0448, 0.0448, 
    0.06976, 0.06976, 0.03488, 0.03488, 0.05216, 0.05216, 0.05216, 
    1.7408, 2.2528, 2.2528, 2.2528, 0.5632, 0.6912, 0.6912, 0.6912, 
    0.6912, 0.9728, 0.9728, 0.2432, 0.2432, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 
    0.32, 0.4416, 0.4416, 0.4416, 0.4416, 0.5632, 0.5632, 0.1408, 
    0.1408, 0.1712, 0.1712, 0.1712, 0.1712, 0.2112, 0.2112, 0.2112, 
    0.2112, 0.0652, 0.0652, 0.0652, 0.0652, 0.0852, 0.0852, 0.0852, 
    0.086, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.106, 0.106, 0.106, 0.106, 0.1352, 
    0.1352, 0.1352, 0.1352, 0.1552, 0.1552, 0.1552, 0.1552, 0.2, 
    0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 
    0.07, 0.075, 0.075, 0.075, 0.075, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 
    0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.1675, 0.1675, 
    0.1675, 0.1675, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.2375, 0.2375, 0.2375, 
    0.2375, 0.2725, 0.2725, 0.2725, 0.2725, 0.3025, 0.3025, 0.3025, 
    0.3025, 0.365, 0.365, 0.365, 0.365, 0.3975, 0.3975, 0.3975, 
    0.3975, 0.47, 0.47, 0.47, 0.47, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.49, 
    0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.51, 0.51, 0.51, 0.51, 
    0.52, 0.52, 0.52, 0.52, 0.53, 0.53, 0.27, 0.46, 0.5, 0.5, 
    0.5, 0.5, 0.54, 0.54, 0.54, 0.54, 0.59, 0.59, 0.59, 0.59, 
    0.59, 0.59, 0.59, 0.59, 0.62, 0.62, 0.62, 0.62, 0.74, 0.37, 
    0.74, 0.37, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.56, 0.56, 0.56, 0.56, 0.1, 
    0.66, 0.66, 0.66, 0.66, 0.66, 0.66, 0.66, 0.66, 0.66, 0.66, 
    0.66, 0.66, 0.72, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 
    0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.52, 0.52, 0.52, 0.52, 
    0.52, 0.535, 0.535, 0.535, 0.535, 0.545, 0.545, 0.545, 0.545, 
    0.545, 0.545, 0.546, 0.545, 0.288, 0.157, 0.288, 0.288, 0.125, 
    0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 
    0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 
    0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
    0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
    0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 
    0.135, 0.135, 0.135, 0.135, 0.135, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.128, 
    0.128, 0.128, 0.128, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.133, 0.133, 
    0.133, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 
    0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 
    0.25, 0.313, 0.313, 0.313, 0.313, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 
    0.378, 0.378, 0.378, 0.378, 0.378, 0.378, 0.378, 0.378, 0.378, 
    0.378, 0.378, 0.378, 0.378, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 
    0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 
    0.18, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.15, 0.15, 
    0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.19, 0.19, 0.19, 0.19, 
    0.19, 0.19, 0.19, 0.19, 0.24, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 
    1.3, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.4, 1.4, 1.12, 1.12, 1.28, 
    1.28, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.75008, 1.75008, 1.75008, 1.75008, 
    2.25008, 2.25008, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.88, 2.88, 2.88, 2.88, 
    3.44, 3.44, 0.86, 0.86, 0.86, 0.86, 0.86, 0.86, 0.86, 0.86, 
    0.86, 0.86, 0.86, 0.86, 0.86, 0.86, 0.86, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 
    0.95, 0.95, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 
    1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.21, 1.21, 
    1.21, 1.21, 1.21, 1.21, 1.21, 1.21, 1.21, 1.21, 1.21, 1.21, 
    1.21, 1.21, 1.21, 0.54, 0.54, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 
    0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 
    0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.24, 0.12, 0.12, 
    0.12, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.15, 
    0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 
    0.18, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
    0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.65, 0.65, 
    0.65, 0.65, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 
    0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 
    1.3, 1.3, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.57, 
    1.57, 1.57, 1.57, 1.62, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 
    0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025)), row.names = c(NA, 
-835L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: they all start at 1 because that's how you set them up: 1 * dividends[1] / dividends[1] = 1. They all have a different start date though, so the plot is a bit confusing.

Comment: Thanks! They all have different start dates because they are dividend payments. I just want to set the data to "1998-09-24" and normalise from there. Should I try something to `group_by` - more all dates which are 1 period before "1998-09-24" and "rename" them to "1998-09-24" and then normalise it from there?

Comment: You can't normalise from "1998-09-24"  onwards if you do not have the data for this date. E.g. for ORCL your data starts in 2009 so you can't standardize with data from 1998.

Comment: hmm your right. Perhaps I should choose a data closer to today to normalise.

Comment: depends on what you want to achieve